# Hybris Datahub Cannot Connect to Hybris

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I am changing the Hybris ports in local.properties as

```
tomcat.http.port=29001
tomcat.ssl.port=29002
tomcat.ajp.port=28009
tomcat.jmx.port=29003
tomcat.jmx.server.port=29004
```

Then, I am changing data hub local.properties as

```
targetsystem.hybriscore.url=http://localhost:29001/datahubadapter
targetsystem.hybriscore.username=admin
targetsystem.hybriscore.password=nimda


datahub.extension.exportURL=http://localhost:29001/datahubadapter
datahub.extension.userName=admin
datahub.extension.password=nimda
```

It throws exception:

```
2017-09-27 15:59:44,457 [INFO] [c.h.d.s.i.PublicationActionHandler] 
Publishing to XXX
2017-09-27 15:59:44,477 [DEBUG] [c.h.d.c.a.i.CoreAdapterService] Creating 
impex for export to: http://localhost:29001/datahubadapter
2017-09-27 15:59:44,480 [DEBUG] 
[c.h.d.s.i.AsynchronousEventPublicationService] Firing data hub event : 
TargetSystemPublicationStartedEvent{publicationId=3519, poolId=0}
2017-09-27 15:59:44,483 [INFO] [c.h.d.c.c.i.DefaultExportClient] 
Authenticating publish to XXX
2017-09-27 15:59:45,496 [ERROR] [c.h.d.s.i.PublicationActionHandler] 
Publication #32 to target system XXX failed
```

Comment: In exception detail :
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:287) ~[jersey-client-2.25.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252) ~[jersey-client-2.25.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684) ~[jersey-client-2.25.jar:na]

Comment: did you try ant clean / all after changes? Because tomcat configurations renew after ant clean.

Comment: Yes, I tried ant clean after changes. I can login to hac and backoffice. I think Hybris works well or some problem with spring security or there is a problem in DataHub configurations.

Comment: When added to datahub local.properties this values, problem is solved.
datahub.core.export.service.oauth.path = /authorizationserver/oauth/token
datahub.core.export.service.oauth.port=9012